# workload not availble on visual studio 2017 setup

Tags: unity, visual-studio

i use vs2017 with unity but now when io want to install it on new pc there is a message says: workload unavailable right now. required conditions are not satisfied. not win10 threshold number1 and number2 build number

Comment: This sounds like a troubleshooting problem you might want to take up with Unity/Microsoft technical support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its all about windows Version.visual studio plugin for unity depends on new updates of windows. i just updated the windows and it worked.